# hexo: Unexpected token '=>' while compiling ejs

Tags: ejs, hexo

I recently updated my hexo project, and almost everything is still ok, except that I now get an error `Unexpected token '=>' while compiling ejs`  from the following section.

I don't recall having this before the update, but if anything `=>` should be more supported now than it was in the past?

Does ejs not support fat arrow, or is this script wrong in some other way?

```
<ul class="list-reset lg:flex justify-end flex-1 items-center">
                <% if (page.lang == "en") { site.pages.data.filter(p => p.lang
                == "en").sort( (p1, p2) => p1.menuorder - p2.menuorder
                ).forEach( function(p, idx) { %> <%- partial( 'menu_item',
                {data: p, page: page} ) %> <% }) %> <%- partial( 'menu_item',
                {data: {path:"", menutitle: "Nederlands"}} ) %> <% } else {
                site.pages.data.filter(p => p.lang == "nl").sort( (p1, p2) =>
                p1.menuorder - p2.menuorder ).forEach( function(p, idx) { %> <%-
                partial( 'menu_item', {data: p} ) %> <% }) %> <%- partial(
                'menu_item', {data: {path:"en_introduction.html", menutitle:
                "English"}} ) %> <% } %>
</ul>
```

(vscode insists on mangling the script, but this should be easier to read)

```
<% if (page.lang == "en") { 
    site.pages.data
        .filter(p => p.lang == "en")
        .sort( (p1, p2) => p1.menuorder - p2.menuorder)
        .forEach( function(p, idx) { %> 
            <%- partial( 'menu_item', {data: p, page: page} ) %> 
        <% }) %> 
        <%- partial( 'menu_item', {data: {path:"", menutitle: "Nederlands"}} ) %> 
<% } else {
    site.pages.data
        .filter(p => p.lang == "nl")
        .sort( (p1, p2) => p1.menuorder - p2.menuorder )
        .forEach( function(p, idx) { %> 
            <%- partial( 'menu_item', {data: p} ) %> 
        <% }) %> 
        <%- partial( 'menu_item', {data: {path:"en_introduction.html", menutitle: "English"}} ) %> 
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 1 of your code snippet you have the opening ejs tag but are missing the closing one as you need to have an opening and closing tag on every line of ejs. I think the error from the arrow function may be due to your code editor looking for a closing tag but instead finding '=>'.

Your code:

```
<% if (page.lang == "en") {
```

with closing tag:

```
<% if (page.lang == "en") { %>
```

I hope this fixes the error